# What should happen when the same coordinates are specified to lineTo()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Let's say I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;
canvas.lineWidth = 20;
canvas.lineCap = 'round';
canvas.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.moveTo(50, 50);
canvas.lineTo(50, 50);
canvas.stroke();
```

I've told the browser to stroke a line on the canvas, but from one location to exactly the same location.  In practice, this seems to cause the browsers I've tested with to render a circle at that location like a "one pixel line", but theoretically, it could be interpreted as a zero-length line and no path drawn.

Does the standard dictate that the renderer has to draw something if I specify "draw from 50,50 to 50,50" when `lineCap` is `round`, or is it an implementation detail that I cannot rely on?

Answer (score 1):

**Correct, the "circle" is an implementation detail that you cannot rely on.**

BTW, that circle is really 2 half-circles. ;-)

Only `lineCap='butt'` will halt the line at exactly x0,y0. So if you render a butted segment with zero length you will see nothing.

`lineCap='round'` will extend the segment beyond x0,y0 and the rounding is half the linewidth. The same extending is true for `lineCap='square'`.

So, you **might** end up with 2 half circles each with radius=20/2=10 that visually form a full circle. You'll see a circle in Chrome & FF, but in Edge you will see nothing.

Comment: This answer seems to give a mixed message - it says that it will extend the segment but then says it might draw nothing.  Which is it?

Comment: Your zero length segment will give different results on different browsers. If you code craziness (zero length lines) then the browsers will not have a standard to apply to your craziness. :-) In other words ... you should test for zero length lines and don't draw them unless you can live with unpredictable results.